# How can I check if the specific TD on a table contains the value i want?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Im new on this field, and i would like to ask how you guys do it if you are trying to check or assert on the table  to be specific that contains "WaterBill" for example. 
In the module listview,  I have column name "Bill Type" and i quick search a WaterBill and I am expecting to have the output WaterBill for all Bill Type column. How do I check if all the elements in the column Bill Type only contains WaterBill? My xpath for example is

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

Note: Every Bill Type on the listview has different TR and in every TR the specific Waterbill is always on the TD[2]

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have table

```
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>         
        <td>Waterbill</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Waterbill</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you can have an xpath to find `td` with value `3` by following xpath

```
'//table/descendant-or-self::td[contains(text(),"3")]'
```

if your table has id you can filter that out by

```
'//table[@id="xyz"]/descendant-or-self::td[contains(text(),"3")]'
```

for selecting nth column you would do sth like this

```
'//table[@border=1]/descendant-or-self::tr/child::td[position()=4 and contains(text(),"3")]'
```

in your specific case xpath will be

```
'//table[@border=1]/descendant-or-self::tr/child::td[position()=2 and contains(text(),"Waterbill")]'
```

*note 2nd row /3rd column will not be selected

Comment: Thank you @sakhunzai!! I'll let  you know if it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

int count=obj.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")).size();                        //get the count of no. of rows in the table

```
    for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)       //loop as per the count of table
    {
        String a=obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]")).getText();  //Retrieving the data from the Td of table in to a string
        if(a.contains("WaterBill"))
        {
            System.out.println("contains WaterBill");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("does not contains WaterBill");
        }
    }
```